# money I lent/ have lent

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-vs-present-perfect

I've read somewhere that: "I want you to pay back the money I lent you", refers to one occasion of lending money and "I want you to pay back the money I've lent you" refers to multiple occasions.

Do other natives agree? Is it ungrammatical to use present perfect for a one-off loan that hasn't been paid back yet?

Comment: I read somewhere that people use context to understand what someone means and only computers rely on rules like "if you use the perfect it means more than one instance of lending". If I only wanted you to pay back some of the money I lent you, I'd say that. If you weren't clear on what money I wanted you to pay back, you'd ask. There are plenty of grammatical statements that are semantically nonsense, and plenty of ungrammatical statements that have a perfectly clear meaning. This sort of hair-splitting isn't very productive in my opinion.

Comment: My question is about the difference between present perfect and past simple in this case.

Comment: a native speaker would use either phrasing for either situation (source: I am a native speaker).  I would probably say "I want you to pay back *all* the money I lent you" for multiple occasions, but really it all depends on the context.

Comment: @ Esther Can I say:  "I want you to pay back the money I've lent you" if I've lent you money once? That's my question.

Comment: Obviously you can. There's nothing about the perfect that has anything to do with  the number of times you have done something.

Comment: There are numerous other answers to the difference between  "present perfect and past simple". Just enter that phrase into the search bar.